# why does using "async" inside of "module.exports" cause: Type Error: "exports" is read-only

Tags: javascript, node.js, async-await, zurb-foundation, commonjs

I have the following, experimental code:

```
//JS File which exports
function consoletest(){
  console.log("HelloRequire!")
}

function commonAJAXCall(){
  return $.get('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1', {

      }).then((response) => {
        response = JSON.stringify(response)
        console.log(response)
        console.log("AJAX happened")
        return response
  })
}

module.exports = {
  doStuff: async () => {
    //await commonAJAXCall()
    consoletest()
    }

  }


//JS File which imports
let eventListeners = require('./lib/eCommerceLogic')

$("#AJAXproductnames").on("click", function(){
   eventListeners.doStuff()
})
```

Now I followed this really GREAT tutorial from March 2019 on how to use async/await and module.exports:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YGHnvrDGmJw

But for some reason, it doesn't work for me :/
When I have the

```
doStuff: async () => {
    //await commonAJAXCall()
    consoletest()
    }
```

async keyword in use, I get the error:

```
Type Error: "exports" is read-only
```

When I remove it, everything works fine, so the error definitely seems to be related to the async keyword.

My code lies inside a ZURB Foundation 6.4 Project, so there's webpack4, babel7 and gulp in action. I don't know if this might cause the error because in the tutorial, everything worked fine and I just don't understand why it won't for me :/

async/await are definitely available, I already spent a day configuring babel7 to work with this ES7 feature ^^

Comment: This might be an issue with webpack and if you use require or import. https://github.com/webpack/webpack/issues/4039  So far many important details are missing (how is this code used, the installed dependencies and the complete code).